# Multiple input parameters to Map function Java 8

Tags: java, data-structures, lambda, java-stream

```
  File inputF = new File("C:\\sample.csv"); //Line 1
  InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(inputF); //Line2
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS)); // Line3
  inputList = br.lines().skip(1).map(createObject).collect(Collectors.toList()); // Line 4 Function createobject below
```

In the fourth line above I am passing the list of lines that I have read from CSV file to function `createObject` below. I also have another csv file which has list of items. Suppose I have read the second file too in the function above .. now how can I pass list of lines in the second file to `createObject` Function along with the first file. I want to pass second file also because I want to check if items from first file are present in second file

```
public static Function<String, YouJavaItem> createObject= (line) -> {
        List<String> firstFile= Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
```

Example : I want to check if firstFile.get(2) say "abc" is present in list of items in file2 {"lmn", "ukl","xyz","abc"}

Comment: So you want to "read all items from a file not present in a second file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `createObject` a `BiFunction<String,List<String>,YourJavaObject>` so it can accept both the current line and the `List<String>` you read from the second file.

You can read the second file into a `List` before reading the first file, because you're going to need its contents for every element of the first:

```
List<String> secondFileContents = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\secondFile"));
```

Now you can use it to pass to your `createObject` - which would need a parameter for it.

```
Path firstFile = Paths.get("C:\\sample.csv");
List<YourJavaItem> result = Files.lines(firstFile).skip(1)
                .map(line -> YourClass.createObject(line, secondFileContents))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As for your example, the `createObject` method could look like this:

```
BiFunction<String,List<String>,YourJavaItem> createObject =
    (line, sfc) -> {
        if ("abc".equals(sfc.get(2))) {
            System.out.println("abc found!");
        }
        return new YourJavaItem(line);
    }
}
```

If you just want to create a `List<String>` not containing the items in the second file, you can just filter:

```
List<String> result = Files.lines(firstFile).skip(1)
         .flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line).stream()
                          .filter(item -> !secondfileContents.contains(item)))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Using an in-place lambda**

If you define your `createObject` as a lambda in the function reading the lines, you can still use the `Function<String,YourJavaObject>` and refer to the locally defined `List<String>` you read from the second file.

```
List<String> secondFileContents = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\secondFile"));
Function<String,YourJavaObject> mapper = line -> {
    if ("abc".equals(secondFileContents.get(2))) {
        System.out.println("abc found!");
    }
    return new YourJavaItem(line);
}
List<YourJavaItem> result = Files.lines(firstFile).skip(1)
                                .map(mapper)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you so much Daniu. I am facing issue compiling the code. class ABC{ public static void main(String[] args){ List<YouJavaItem> result = Files.lines(firstFile).skip(1) //LINE 1
.map(line -> createObject(line, secondFileContents)) //Line 2
.collect(Collectors.toList());}  public static BiFunction<String, List<String>,YouJavaItem> createObject = (line,sfc) -> { } I am getting compilation error at Line 1 that "Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)" and Line 2 "The method createObject(String, List<String>) is undefined for the type StreamAPI"

Comment: @Neha The `BiFunction` needs to return a value, and if you declare it locally you need to do `.map(line -> createObject.apply(line, secondFileContents)`. On mobile right now though so I can't try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the second file is not too big, says, it's affordable to store the entire content in memory, then the optimal solution is obviously to load and store in a `HashSet`. That brings the lowest cost for checking first file's items existence.

```
        Set<String> file2Items;
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file2Name))) {
            file2Items = Files.lines(Paths.get(file2Name)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error reading " + file2Name);
        }
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(file1Name))) {
            inputList = lines.filter(x -> !file2Items.contains(x)).map(createObject).collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // any exception handling you prefer.
        }
```

*If the file size is significant, reading a file line by line can help to save up to 50% of needed memory, as you don't need to load an entire file as a collection of lines and then convert it into objects successfully before the lines are eligible of GC*

Answer (score -1):

> now how can I pass list of lines in the second file to createObject Function along with the first file. I want to pass second file also **because I want to check if items from first file are present in second file**

If you want to check whether items from first file are present in second one, you don't need to merge the two files, just map items in the second file and the item you want to check in first file using `createObject`, then use `Collection.contains` method.

More specifically, you want to check if firstFile.get(2) is present in list of items in file2:

```
static class YourJavaItem {
    YourJavaItem(String word) {

    }
}

public static Function<String, Stream<YourJavaItem>> createObject = (line) -> {
    return Arrays.stream(line.split(",")).map(YourJavaItem::new);
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File inputF1 = new File("C:\\sample.csv");
    File inputF2 = new File("C:\\sample.csv");

    InputStream inputFS1 = new FileInputStream(inputF1);
    InputStream inputFS2 = new FileInputStream(inputF2);

    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS1));
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS2));

    Set<YourJavaItem> set = br2.lines().flatMap(createObject).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    YourJavaItem keyword = br1.lines().flatMap(createObject).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(2);
    boolean whatYouWant = set.contains(keyword);

    // Don't forget to close file resources
}
```

But if you insist merging the two files, you can use `Stream.concat`:

`Stream.concat(br1.lines(), br2.lines()).flatMap(createObject)`